# KQL time graph number of vulnerabilities

Tags: azure, kql, azure-security

I have a query that fetches the number of unique vulnerabilities found in our images in our Azure Container Registry:

```
securityresources
 | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments'
 | where id matches regex  '(.+?)/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/dbd0cb49-b563-45e7-9724-889e799fa648/'
 | parse id with  registryResourceId '/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/' *
 | parse registryResourceId with  * "/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/" registryName
 | extend imageDigest = tostring(properties.additionalData.imageDigest), repository = tostring(properties.additionalData.repositoryName)
 | project
         registryName, 
         repository, 
         imageDigest,
         severity = properties.status.severity,
         vulnId = properties.id,
         displayName = properties.displayName,
         description = properties.description,
         remediation = properties.remediation,
         category = properties.category,
         impact = properties.impact,
         timeGenerated = properties.timeGenerated
| distinct tostring(vulnId)
| summarize count()
```

I would like to have a graph that shows the number of vulnerabilities over a period of time so we can see (visually) that the number of vulnerabilities are going down (or up), but I have no clue on how to do this. Hopefully someone can help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `distinct tostring(vulnId) | summarize count()`, try either of the following:

- `summarize dcount() by bin(timeGenerated, 1h)`
- `make-series dcount() on timeGenerated step 1h`

and then add a `| render timechart` at the end

e.g:

```
securityresources
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments'
| where id matches regex  '(.+?)/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/dbd0cb49-b563-5e7-9724-889e799fa648/'
| extend vulnId = tostring(properties.id)
| summarize dcount(vulnId) by bin(timeGenerated, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Comment: Hi Yoni, thanks for replying and thinking along! Tried what you suggested, but got some errors. I put the queries and errors on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/gZfbnetr.

Comment: The timeGenerated here is when the an image (tag/digest) was created). I don't want to check against that timestamp but more against the actual time that query is done. So today the value of unqie vulnId maybe 200, but when running the query tomorrow it can be 190 because we did some fixes.

Comment: (1) my reply was under the assumption you're using the full version of the Kusto Query Language, as supported by services like Azure Data Explorer. it seems you're using a different version of the language, used by Azure Resource Graph. unfortunately, i'm less familiar with that and its limitations - but it seems wrong that you're running `tostring(properties.timeGenerated)`. did you intend to call `todatetime()` instead? (2) if i understand your second comment correctly, you can remove the `by bin(timeGenerated, 1h)`, to get the summary over the full data set

Comment: Hi Yoni, sorry should have mentioned that I am using Azure Resource Graph indeed. With DataExplorer I don't think ASC is a datasource you can query on. Then I would have to export the ARG results to csv, store it in a blob or something and then use ADE to query it.

timeGenerated is part of a properties field . In this case timeGenerated is the date+time when an image+tag (digest) was created.